no audio when encoding 5.1 ch audio to opus
when i was encoding a dts 5.1 ch audio that had the layout of C L R Ls Rs LFE , file using ffmpeg via libopus ,  i found that the resulting
file did not play in vlc, due to the channel layout being rewritten to L R C Lb Rb LFE. however if downmixed to stereo, there would be sound.
command used:
ffmpeg -i out.dts -c:a libopus -b:a 160k -af "channelmap=channel_layout=5.1" out.opus


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I was having a similar issue and it looks like mine was a regression with VLC and a fix has been merged for the next release (3.0.22). The original bug report has a test file that doesn't work for me on VLC 3.0.21.
Original bug report & fix
https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/27808
New bug report & fix
https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/28671

I noticed the same thing with VLC 3.0.21. As I am writing this comment the 3.0.22 is not out yet, so you can get the last nightly build there: https://nightlies.videolan.org/
